# Can't access "reasons for" links in closure box

Tags: bug, close-reasons

Until very recently (maybe less than a couple of days ago) if I voted to close a question, I could re-open the close box and find a hyper-link to a page that explained why shopping questions get closed (for instance). I could then copy that hyper-link and add a comment to the original question such as: -

```
[Reason why shopping questions get closed](hyper-link)
```

I did this to be a little helpful to the person raising the question.

I can't easily find that hyper link any more so can anyone direct me?

### EDIT

[This is the link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) I'm referring to.

Comment: It seems to have happened since the "community-specific reason" change, at the moment it seems the only way is to open the dialog on a random question without actually closing and copying [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Comment: Thanks but that's not the same page that succinctly explained that shopping questions are off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was being dumb - it can be found here: -

[image]

Comment: +1 for being dumb, at least other users will be able to find this if they search for it on the meta